# How to multiplex subtitles with avi or mp4 in Linux?

Tags: linux, subtitles, avidemux, embedding

I have been searching something which can multiplex subtitle with video files in Linux environment. The key thing is that it should softly embed the subtitle to video, not encode again. (like avidemux). After this multiplexing process, user should be able to open/close subtitle using VLC for example.

While searching that, I found a software which can do exactly what I need, named AVI-Mux GUI in Windows environment. However, I need these software's Linux alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://home.gna.org/subtitleeditor/) may be helpful. If not, then try [this](http://ubuntu.sabza.org/2008/03/02/ubuntu-linux-subtitles-video-editing-and-dvd-authoring/) or [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-subtitles.html).

Comment: When I was googling, I have found tools that was mentioned in these articles but unfortunately these are not the ones that I search. Most of them hardly embed the subtitle to video file...

Comment: That's not always possible. It depends on the file format. To get an overview of what actually is possible, have a look at [a comparison of container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats#Caption_.28Subtitle.29_formats_supported)

Answer (score 3):

The AVI container format does not support embedded (muxed) subtitles at all - it only supports hard subs, which requires re-encoding the video with the subtitles actually in each video frame.

To have muxed subtitles you need to use either the MKV or MP4 container formats, depending on the subtitle format.

Your AVI files can be remuxed into either container, again depending on the video and audio codecs. See [Comparison of container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) on Wikipedia for compatibility tables.

I have found that MKV supports far more combinations than MP4

The [MKVToolNix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) package is available for Linux and will do everything you need

For MP4 the tool to use is [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/)

If you need more info on the difference between a container format (e.g. AVI, MP4, MKV etc.) and a codec (e.g. DivX, Xvid, H.264 etc.) then [Digital container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_%28digital%29) and it's linked articles is a good place to start.